# How do I derive the equation for current as a function of time \$I(t)\$ through resistor in this CLCR circuit schematic with a sine wave AC source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, ac, filter, inductor

How do I derive \$I(t)\$ through the resistor for the circuit schematic below?

[image: CLCR circuit schematic]

What method should be used.

So far, I have tried mesh analysis for the 3 meshes using KVL but the system of equations became too difficult to solve. I have also tried Laplace transform, which I don't quite understand how I would use in this circuit. Would it be helpful to perform transient analysis for \$t > 0\$?

I just want to find \$I(t)\$ across the resistor \$R_1\$. How do I derive that?

Comment: Current goes through a component, voltage is across it.

Comment: Using Laplace would be easy -- what don't you understand about it?  Please _edit your question_ to expand on where you get stuck.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this new question is much different to your [previous](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630660/how-do-i-derive-the-equation-for-current-in-a-pi-filter-circuit-with-a-dc-source). For instance, you still haven't fully taken into consideration the comment I made on your earlier answer regarding C1 being directly connected to a voltage source.

Comment: @TimWescott I am stuck on the KVL part.

Comment: @TimWescott can you answer [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631008/how-could-i-perform-circuit-analysis-using-laplace-transform-and-derive-it-acr) question please.

Comment: I see that you have asked this same question before.  Those of us who answer questions tend to _read all of them_, so asking a question twice isn't helpful.  I see that _that_ question has been closed because it lacks detail **this is Stackexchange, you are encouraged to edit your questions**.  Why don't you go _back_ to that question, and _fix it so that it can be answered_?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as written in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630660/how-do-i-derive-the-equation-for-current-in-a-pi-filter-circuit-with-a-dc-source/630669#630669) answer the current through the resistor is given by:

$$\text{I}_4\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\sin\left(\omega\left(t-\tau\right)+\varphi\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{C}_2\text{L}\text{R}_4\text{s}^2+\text{Ls}+\text{R}_4}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\text{d}\tau\tag1$$

Using the values of your components, we will find:

$$\text{I}_4\left(t\right)=\frac{60000000}{11\sqrt{7999999}}\int_0^t\sin\left(100\pi\left(t-\tau\right)\right)\exp\left(-\frac{250\tau}{11}\right)\sin \left(\frac{250 \sqrt{7999999}\tau}{11}\right)\text{d}\tau\tag2$$

Comment: I put up a new question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631008/how-could-i-perform-circuit-analysis-using-laplace-transform-and-derive-it-acr)